# Heroku DNS target pointing .herokudns.com even after removing SSL

Tags: heroku

I have tried configuring SSL on Heroku which changed my DNS target from abc.herokuapp.com to abc.herokudns.com.

I removed the SSL now, however the DNS target is still pointing to abc.herokudns.com instead of abc.herokuapp.com

How do I fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to remove the domain?

```
heroku domains:remove yourdomain.com
```